# xubuntu 11.10 alpha 3 release?

Tags: xubuntu, 11.10

As far as I know Xubuntu 11.10 Alpha 3 was not released due to some problems with the cd image, but will it be released later or is the beta1 going to be the next development release in 11.10 cycle? I can't find any info about that...

Comment: You might try asking on the mailing-list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/xubuntu-devel And of course, there is always the daily image: http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha3 will not be released. However, you are welcome to download and install the daily image. Please read the [Technical Overview](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview) for the issues and workarounds. We do expect to release Beta1 on schedule.